How to put a different system into dualboot?
I need some advice. Let me first outline the situation:
I have 2 hard drives (HDD), on HDD 1 is Windows 7 in dualboot (GRUB bootloader) together with Debian 12 KDE Plasma, on HDD 2 is only Linux Mint 22.
Sometimes I want to play some older games, so I turn on Windows 7, other times I need to go to internet banking, so I manually swap one disk for the other in the PC and boot the more secure and updated Mint.
The question is - can I somehow delete Debian and copy Linux Mint from HDD 2 to HDD 1 instead? So that it still works dualboot with Windows 7?
I would like to avoid a clean install, there is data on the Mint disk that I would like to preserve.
Thanks for any advice.

Theoretically doable if you have the same or more space available after deleting the Debian partition(s) that's currently used by the Mint installation in the other drive. That said, 1. It's risky especially when dealing with very old hardware. The risk is data loss,precisely what you say you want to avoid by not doing what you should do instead - reinstall Mint -; 2. After "moving" you'll need to reinstall GRUB and that's a problem in itself if you don't know what you're doing. The most important point is #3: If you're asking this question you shouldn't do it, period.

But congrats for being responsible by using an up-to-date Linux OS for your daily life instead of the unsupported and dangerous Win7 that's only for "old games" you say. However, if you let it connect to the internet then MANY nasty things can and will happen irrespective of the security that your Linuxes bring (not so much as you might think if you aren't careful, the user is always the weakest link).

@ChanganAuto, thanks for comment. Yes, when I boot Windows 7, I play only old offline games (installed from CD´s). Win7 is not connected to Internet, Linux Mint is.

Since you want to keep Win 7 isolated, test running it in a VM, such as VirtualBox. My experience is that there is little or no perceptible loss of responsiveness, so it should not hurt game-play. The VM adds yet another layer of isolation security. The VM can run on either Debian or Mint, or be moved from one to another.
